# Can't make sense of Exercism.io

Tags: javascript

I just started out to learn Javascript and I think that coding while watching videos is the best way to master a language. 
I learned the following topics in Javascript (BRIEFLY):
 - Basic JS Operators
 - JS Arrays
 - JS Objects
 - If-else condition and loops

After learning these, I entered Exercism.io because I have read in some reddit comments that exercism.io is a good place for beginners to practice javascript. But I couldn't make any sense of the simple "Hello World" program in Exercism. I mean, you just write console.log("Hello World") in (most) "Hello world" programs since it a very very basic program, right? If yes, then what in the world are these:

```
export const hello = () => {
  throw new Error("Remove this statement and implement this function");
};
```

and this:

```
import { hello } from './hello-world';

describe('Hello World', () => {
  test('Say Hi!', () => {
    expect(hello()).toEqual('Hello, World!');
  });
});
```

What  is " => " or "export" or "import...from"?
There are tutorials on Youtube how to setup Exercism and solve the "Hello World" program but none of them explain these complex topics.

So, can anyone give me clear directions on the topics that I have to learn now to be able to make sense of these codes? TIA!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's mostly boilerplate. If the directions are clear, all you need to figure out is what to put in the body of the `hello` function block in order to produce the desired output - eg, for this exercise, you'd want

```
export const hello = () => {
  return 'Hello, World';
};
```

You'd follow the same pattern for any exercise - figure out the function in which you're supposed to type, and type it.

`=>` is arrow function syntax. You don't have to worry about it, it doesn't matter - you could do the same thing with

```
export function hello() {
  return 'Hello, World';
};
```

You shouldn't need to care about the imports/exports either. They're a way for the environment to connect the function you write to the tests to see if the function is producing the correct output - it's built into the exercise, it's not something you need to (or should) mess with in any way. Just write what you need to in the upper function and run the test.

Reading the tests below will help give you an idea of what sort of outputs are expected for each input - for example

```
expect(hello()).toEqual('Hello, World!')
```

is saying, basically, that `hello() === 'Hello, World!'` should be `true`.

Comment: You explanation is really nice @CertainPerformance. 
Two questions thou: 
1) "Just write what you need to in the upper function and run the test"
- What did you mean by "upper function?"
2) You saw the code:
export const hello = () => {
  throw new Error("Remove this statement and implement this function");
};
AND you immediately knew to omit the "Throw new." What was the thought process/knowledge that you used when you replaced "Throw new" with return? What does "Throw new" mean?

Comment: By "upper function", I was referring to the function in your upper code block - the code block starting with `export const hello = () => {`. The function says by default `throw new Error("Remove this statement and implement this function");`, and the test below invokes `hello()` and examines its return value, so it was obvious that the `throw new Error` line should be removed and replaced with your own implementation.

Comment: It would have been clearer if they used `// Implement the function here` instead, the `throw new Error()` is weird

Comment: I agree with you, it is kinda weird for a beginner like I am.
Have you used exercism.io? I would like to learn JS through solving problems so do you think Exercism would be a good place to fulfill this purpose? Is it a beginner friendly platform? I mean, I got into a bit of trouble during the first problem but since you helped me understand not to worry about these "weird parts", can I just find the "right function," from now on, to put code inside and hopefully solve the problems? Or are there more concepts that I need to learn before I can start solving the "easy" problems in Exercism?

Comment: I've never been there, but I'm familiar with similar sites, there are many of them. Once you understand how to solve one exercise, there probably aren't any similar gotchas to watch out for with the rest - the rest should just be programming.